Direct sum and isomorphism
Let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{B}(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra, $\,H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $\xi\in H,\,\xi\neq 0$ such that $\overline{\mathcal{A}\xi}=H.$ We consider the projection $P$ onto $\overline{\mathcal{A}^\prime \xi}.$ Then, $P$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$ and the map $$\phi\colon \mathcal{A}^\prime \to \mathcal{A}^\prime P,\,\,\phi(X)=X P$$ is a $*$-isomorphism, i.e. $\mathcal{A}^\prime\cong \mathcal{A}^\prime P.$ On the other hand $$\mathcal{A}^\prime=\mathcal{A}^\prime P\oplus \mathcal{A}^\prime P^{\perp}.$$
What can we say for the vNa $\mathcal{A}^\prime P^{\perp}$ ?

$A’ = A’P \oplus A’P^\perp$ is not true in the first place. For example, when $A = B(H)$, then $A’ = \mathbb{C}$ and $P$ is the projection onto the span of $\xi$. Both $A’P$ and $A’P^\perp$ equal $\mathbb{C}$, but certainly it’s not true that $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$.

It is true that both $A’P$ and $A’P^\perp$ are direct summands of $A’$. They are just not the complement of each other.

Thank you. I got it.


What can we say for the vNa $\mathcal{A}^\prime P^{\perp}$ ?

In general, nothing. If $\xi$ is separating for $\mathcal A$, then $P=I$ and $\mathcal A'P^\perp=\{0\}$. At the other end of the spectrum, if $\mathcal A=B(H)$, then $\mathcal A'=\mathbb C\,I$ and hence $\mathcal A'P^\perp\simeq\mathcal A'$.
